# How do I make a div inside a grid stretch beyond the grid?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a container, with a 12 column grid and 30px margin on left and right of the grid system
[image]

this is the change in grid layout at 768 px, see how the blue div which occupied 8 columns is now extending beyond the 8 columns, covering the margins too.
[image]

I need help with how to do this? I cannot remove the blue div out of the grid.

I have tried setting width of blue div to 100vw and left-margin to -30px, it worked but I face weird issues in different conditions in dev tools, nevertheless I want to avoid the use of vw. please help me out.

Comment: If you don't like the negative margins you can always do what I sometimes do and duplicate the blue div, then hide/show them alternately, depending on the viewport width. I.e. at 768px and below, the blue div is not inside the 12 col grid: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/g79fy8p3/ (bootstrap solution)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use negative margins:

Eg:

```
margin-left: -30px;
margin-right: -30px;
```

**Do not set WIDTH**

Comment: so my property would become:

grid columns 1 to 8
left margin -30px right margin -30px?

the blue div's width is 100% though..

Comment: the issue with negative margin is raised when you set a fixed witdth, if I've understood your issue

Comment: there is no width on the blue div, its just put from column 1-8. now i added left and right margin of -30 and its perfect.. is this a good practice though? could i run into some trouble later on? I am trying to make a responsive page. the left and right margins for the grid are always gonna be 30px, so I can do this right?

Comment: No trouble at all, you are simply compensating a external padding. If you want to remove margin at some responsive breakpoints just fix it in your responsive setup

Comment: In many grid systems you'll find out that rows element enclosing column have a negative margin, eg check https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/1770691b339bdbf17de5e8824158b358dc0284a9/dist/css/bootstrap-grid.css at line 81

Answer (score 0):

I would refrain from using negative margins as they can create new problems.

I would rather use an absolute positioning.

```
.child-div {
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    right:0;
}
```

Comment: doing this ruins other things in that page. i have many more elements around, absolute positioning is making it fit the viewport but overall layout of the page is changing. What problems can -ve margins cause? I will always have left and right margins for grids fixed to 30px, if i make the margins for div in grid to -30px each side, what can happen in any case?

Comment: I assumed you wanted full screen width, as the blue div showed. It depends on your HTML-Code. If you see no 'spooky' actions going on, you can use negative margins.   They may shift surrounding divs and its usually hard to debug the problem if something like this happens.

Answer (score 0):

use negative margins to your gird parent class. This margin should be same as your gutter space. like below snippet.

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="grid-8"></div>
 <div class="grid-4"></div>
</div>

.row{
 margin-left: -30px;
 margin-right: -30px;
}
.row > .grid-8 {
 width: 60%;
 padding:0 30px;
}
.row > .grid-4 {
 width: 40%;
 padding:0 30px;
}
```